# CSS selector: how to make 2 spans each fill 50% of their parent's width?

Tags: css, width, parent-child

This doesn't works:

**Given an HTML such:**

```
<body>
<div class="list">
    <span class=" level">hello</span>
    <span class="logic-english">world!</span>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <span class=" level">Or should</span>
    <span class="logic-english">I say....</span>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <span class=" level">something else</span>
    <span class="logic-english">such as...</span>
</div>
<div class="list">
    <span class=" level">Goodbye</span>
    <span class="logic-english">world!</span>
</div>
</body>
```

**a CSS such:**

```
body { width: 100%; }
.list { border: 1px solid #333; margin: 3px; }

.list { font-size: 0.8em; min-width: 50% ; display: inline; }
.list:nth-child(4n+3), .list:nth-child(4n+4) { background: #FFAAAA; width: 100%; }
```

**[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4zddx/9/)**.

Also, **how to make my 2 spans each fill 50% of their parent's width ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the elements to `display:inline-block` and reduce the width to account for margins. You may want to move to a more fixed width using pixels to make the `.list` elements take up half the container.

**CSS**

```
.list { 
    font-size: 0.8em; 
    min-width: 47% ; 
    display: inline-block; 
}
.list:nth-child(4n+3), .list:nth-child(4n+4) { 
    background: #FFAAAA; 
    width: 47%; 
}
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/4zddx/11/